# Laravel Send email using AWS SES

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, laravel-5.7

I have the following config from aws in my laravel 5.7 app (admin.my-app.com) that i'm maintaining.

my .env

```
MAIL_MAILER=ses
SES_KEY=aws_key_here
SES_KEY_SECRET=aws_secret_key_here
SES_REGION=us-east-1
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@my-app.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

my config/mail.php

```
<?php

return [
    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),
//other configs
```

my config/services.php

```
<?php

return [
    'ses' => [
        'key' => env('SES_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('SES_KEY_SECRET'),
        'region' => env('SES_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
    ],
    //other configs
```

Code to trigger email sending

```
    public function approveKyc(Request $request, $userId)
    {
        $model = User::on('mysql2')->find($userId);

        $this->actionKyc($userId, 'is_verified');


        $model->notify(new KycApproved());

        return response()->json([
            'name' => 'New KYC Docs',
            'status' => 'Approved'
        ]);
    }
```

I've also checed composer file **"aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.86",** is installed.

With the above code i'm getting error message

> exception
> :
> "Swift_TransportException"
> file
> :
> "/var/www/my-app/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php"
> line
> :
> 460
> message
> :
> "Expected response code 354 but got code "503", with message "503 RCPT command expected\r\n""

I tested sending email with mailtrap it works fine.  Additionally I used smtp settings from cpanel account it was also working (Email sent sucessfully).

Using aws is not sending the email.

I'm also using the above aws config in another laravel 10 app with sub domain  (api.myapp.com). It works fine there.

Can anyone help me figure-out what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

AWS SES has a "Sandbox" mode that comes with several restrictions. Due to these restrictions, you can only send mail to verified email addresses or domains, or to the Amazon SES mailbox simulator. However, if you're trying to send to an unverified email address while in Sandbox mode, SES will reject the send request. You should get Approvement from AWS team before using it in prod.

Comment: AWS SES has been moved out of sandbox